# deploy asp website in android application?

Tags: android, asp-classic

I want to deploy my asp website in android application. I am basically making a android app in which i want to add all the functionality of my asp page like updation into server databases etc.
I have full functionality of my asp website .
Please suggest me how to do it without the use of webservices as I do not want to make webservices for the created website :/

Comment: You don't have a choice if you want your android app and your web application to communicate you need web services.

Comment: is there any easy way of making a webservice for already created asp pages ??? as i am new to webservices ?? any guidance or any simple sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without web services, it's next to impossible. Remember, incorporating total functionality of your ASP site into Android app might not be feasible at all. Some very heavy features should be axed. Web services will help you give specific values for operations. They'll ease your work.

Comment: Yous should refer to MSDN or related tags on this site for that. Maybe this can help : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040%28v=office.14%29.aspx